# How do I do an SQL query based on a foreign key field?

Tags: sql

I have the following tables:

**people:**

```
id, name
```

**parent:**

```
id, people_id, name
```

I have tried the following:

```
SELECT * FROM people
  LEFT JOIN parent ON people.id = parent.people_id
  WHERE parent.name != 'Carol';
```

How do I find all the people whose parent's name is not Carol?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Please specify the RDBMS you are using

Comment: How to link child with parent ?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yes. I have added my query on the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try below code

```
select people.name from people
inner join parent on people.id=parent.people_id
where parent.name not in ('Carol')
```

Comment: Thanks. One question. What will happen if I use LEFT JOIN instead of INNER JOIN?

Comment: if you use left join then also result will be same

Comment: and if you think any people exist without parent then left join is better choice but if all people have parent then inner join and left join will be provide the same result

Comment: If you wants to know more about join go to the link: `http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp`

Answer (score 0):

If the two tables are to be queried by using Foreign Key.

1. If you want to get all records from one table that have some related entry in a second table then use Inner join

   Select * from People INNER JOIN parent ON people.id = parent.people_id
   WHERE parent.name <> 'Carol'
2. Similarly LEFT JOIN will get all records from the LEFT linked table but if you have selected some columns from the RIGHT table, if there is no related records, these columns will contain NULL

Answer (score 0):

First of all, why would you need two tables? why can't you have a single table named "Person" with ID,Name,ParentID columns

Where ParentID will be optional and reference the ID if it has got parent.

And run the following query

```
select * from PERSON where Name not like 'Carol%' and ParentID IS NOT NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM people WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM parent WHERE people_id = id AND name <> 'Carol')

Answer (score 0):

First of all the table structure you have taken restrict the future growth. Like in future if you want to add parents of your parents then it wont work in this table structure. 
You can do like :
id | parent_id | people_name

Here you can make parent_id null for the parent and add parent_id as id for those who have parent. Here to retrieve you have to use SELF join(join in the same table)

Answer (score 0):

`

```
Select * from people P
INNER JOIN parent PA ON PA.people_id = P._id
where PA.name not in ('Carol')
```

`

Difference between INNER JOIN and LEFT OUTER JOIN
is 
1) INNER JOIN bring only similar data between two table
for ex if in people table parent_id table is nullable then it will not discard the complete row,but in case of LEFT OUTER JOIN it will bring all the rows from LEFT table as well as related table from right table.with all null in right joined row..